# Neo4j in Android using REST

Tags: android, rest, neo4j

I have been trying to use Neo4j in my Android app. So I wrote the following code which should just get the response from the server.

```
Button mButton;
EditText mEditText;
private static final String SERVER_ROOT_URI = "http://localhost:7474/db/data/";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    mEditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.myText);

    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


                WebResource resource= Client.create()
                        .resource(SERVER_ROOT_URI);

                ClientResponse response=resource.get(ClientResponse.class);

                String s=(String.format("GET on [%s], status code [%d]",
                        SERVER_ROOT_URI, response.getStatus() ));
                mEditText.setText(s);

                response.close();
        }
    });
}
```

But when I run this I get the following error:

```
06-25 21:05:54.706  17180-17180/com.example.atleastic.neo4japplication1 W/System.err﹕ at com.example.atleastic.neo4japplication1.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:35)
06-25 21:05:54.706  17180-17180/com.example.atleastic.neo4japplication1 W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5409)
06-25 21:05:54.707  17180-17180/com.example.atleastic.neo4japplication1 W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
06-25 21:05:54.707  17180-17180/com.example.atleastic.neo4japplication1 W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-25 21:05:54.709  17180-17180/com.example.atleastic.neo4japplication1 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.VerifyError: com/sun/jersey/core/impl/provider/entity/MimeMultipartProvider
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructors(Class.java:498)
            at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.getInstance(ComponentConstructor.java:174)
            at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.__getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:166)
            at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:137)
            at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getComponent(ProviderServices.java:256)
            at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getServices(ProviderServices.java:160)
            at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBodyFactory.java:176)
            at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:162)
            at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.init(Client.java:342)
            at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.access$000(Client.java:118)
            at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$1.f(Client.java:191)
            at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$1.f(Client.java:187)
            at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
            at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:187)
            at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:159)
            at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(Client.java:669)
            at com.example.atleastic.neo4japplication1.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:35)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4222)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17620)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5409)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you running this on an emulator or phone?

Comment: on my phone... Is that the reason??

Comment: see this: http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html

Comment: Probably should change the localhost URI too.